# What would be the difference in the voltage transfer curves of this two circuits, assuming the op-amps are not ideal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, bias, inverting-amplifier

How does the resistor connecting the non-inverting terminal to ground affect the transfer curve?

[image: Circuit 2]
[image: Circuit 1]

Comment: When is the output=0V? What should Rc be connected to if you wanted 0V out at Vcc/2? What is the input offset if Iin*R from input bias current is large? What should Rc be?

Comment: It doesn't affect the transfer curve. It affects offset errors due to the input bias currents.

Comment: Depending upon the topology of the input diff-pairs (especially cascaded to reduce Miller Effect), charge blowback onto the RC can upset the region near zero-crossing.